# ios custom back button (NOT in the navi bar)

Tags: ios, navigation, back

i'm building my own navigation between views and i have the navi bar hidden by purpose. still, i need a button **inside the view** (read outside the navi bar) that would behave like "back" button. is there such method to call that could be assigned to a custom button?

i tried standard push segues, but looping back will create new instances and I just need a standard back behavior (that will destroy the current instance).

i guess it's obvious, but somehow i've been missing it. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a button as normal in your view, then connect it to a method that pops the view from the stack.  Something like this:

```
- (IBAction) pressedBackButton:(UIButton *)sender {
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```